# Regular Expression For Set of Strings Not Containing OOO

Tags: regular-expressions

The following is my attempt at coming up with a regular expression for the set of binary strings that do not contain $000$:

$(1 + 01 + 001)^*(\epsilon + 0 + 00)$

I'm going to need it for a proof. So, I'd like to know if it is correct before proceeding with the proof.

Comment: Looks fine to me.